# Where is orange.MakeRandomIndices functions in Orange 3

Tags: orange

I am trying to migrate an Old Orange 2 project to the new Orange 3 platform, There are many modules which seem to be missing from Orange 3,

To start with could not find the orange.MakeRandomIndices.Stratified in Orange package, Also the core, py seems to be replaced,

Checked the Changelog but could not find any history,

Is there any place where I can find the replacements for the Orange 2 functions to Orange 3?